# setting an session[:auth_token] in a RSspec controller spec

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to set an auth_token value in a controller spec. I have the following:

```
describe ApiEditController do
  before do
    session[:auth_token]='abc123' #  doesn't work
  end

  it 'should edit item' do
    # lets create a location
    #....
  end
end
```

but when I inspect the session, I get no mention of the auth_token:

```
{"format"=>"json", "flash"=>#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007fe592813cb8 @used=#<Set: {}>, @closed=false, @flashes={}, @now=nil>}
```

If I do the same via web interface, I get:

```
{"session_id"=>"f16e0a6a0b4942bcad2fd191b49c9078", "the_last_url"=>"http://localhost:3000/arc/menus/12/edit", "_csrf_token"=>"MuQfgciiZjVpaAYiwrbDHGvcyChf6m0ex2QV8GHzOIs=", "auth_token"=>"vfieGDt_iEmSQjllLL5N6g"}
```

Why am I not getting the auth_token value in my spec request? Is it accessing the Rack::Middleware differently?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.session` instead of just `session`

Comment: it looks like `request.session['auth_token']='abc123'` did it, if you edit answer, I'll accept.